# mostrar texto de pagina principal en un modal html

Tags: html5

hola tengo una pagina que muestra diferentes productos en los cuales por medio de un boton muestra un cuadro modal y quisiera que el nombre que tiene ese producto se mostrara en mi ventana modal,
los datos no están guardados en una base de datos. gracias por su ayuda.

código donde se muestra el nombre de el producto

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 pb-3 ">
            <div class="card card-custom bg-white border-white border-0" style="height: 90%">
              <div class="card-custom-avatar text-center">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="" style="width: 100%;"/>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body " style="overflow-y: auto">
                <h4 class="card-title text-wnaranja text-center">PRODUCTO</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="card-footer text-center" style="background: inherit; border-color: inherit;">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Mostrar</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

parte de el modal donde quisiera que se muestre el nombre de el producto

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <label for="producto" class="form-label">PRODUCTO</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="producto" name="producto"  value="" readonly>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer con un atributo `data-*` en el botón. Segun veo, estas usando bootstrap. En su documentación tienen justo el ejemplo de variar el contenido de un modal dependiendo del botón que lo abra:

[BS 4.6](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/modal/#varying-modal-content)

[BS 5.0](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#varying-modal-content)

Algo más o menos así (basado en la doc):

```
<div class="card-footer text-center" style="background: inherit; border-color: inherit;">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" data-nombre="producto-1">Mostrar</a>
</div>
```

Y en JS:

```
var modal = document.querySelector('selector-de-tu-modal')
modal.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  // El botón que abre el modal
  var button = event.relatedTarget
  var producto = button.getAttribute('data-nombre')
  
  // Inserta el nombre en el modal.
  var tituloModal = modal.querySelector('.modal-title')
  tituloModal.textContent = producto
})
```

Si no usas Bootstrap, la idea general es la misma, puedes guardar el nombre del producto como atributo `data-*` y añadir un evento para que al dar clic se actualice el título del modal usando JS.

Comment: Gracias por tu conocimiento, intentare adaptarlo.